# Explode array from other array

Tags: php, laravel, explode

i need to explode

```
$string = "arraytext,carsType:bmw,jep";
```

so the ouput should be like

```
{ 
    arraytext,
    carsType:{
      bmw,
      jep
    }
}
```

Comment: What rules make arraytext one element and bmw,jep be a sub array?

Comment: @NigelRen it should be :

Comment: What happens if the string continues after Jeep? What if there is boattypes after. How do you close one array and open the next?